# Excel Sub/Function to Return a percentage based on completed items in a sublist based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to create a sub or function that will output a percentage of the sub-assignments that are complete/not late. This list adds items using copy and paste, the "category" is inputed by user and the "categorysub" uses =concatentate(category+"sub"). The date in the top is the =now() function. I am adding the ability to add more "subs" with a macro. The add item button simply copy and pastes the range of the 2nd item.

I would like the sub/fun to:

1) Count the number of total "subs" for a given category item (Not every single one in the workbook only for a single "Issue" block. as shown by red box)

2) Count the number of completed "subs" for a given category item / number on time (not past the due date as checked against the current date)

3) Output the number of completed/on time subs over the total sub items

4) If all items are complete output "Complete" 
[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
Public Function Complt(category As String)
Dim loc     As Range
loc = Application.Caller

Dim categoryCell As Range
categoryCell = Cell(loc.row, "C")

Dim categorySub As String
categorySub = category + "sub"

Dim subcat  As Range
subcat = Cell(categoryCell.row - 1, "C")

Dim assignedDateCell As Range

Dim complCount As Integer
complCount = 0

Dim ActComplDate As Range

Dim numberofsubs As Integer
numberofsubs = 0

Do While subcat.Text = categorySub
    numberofsubs = numberofsubs + 1

    assigendDateCell = Cell("G", subcat.row)
    ActComplDate = Cell("H", subcat.row)
    If assignedDateCell.Value <= Sheet2.Cells(1, "G") Or IsEmpty(ActComplDate) = False Then
        complCount = complCount + 1
        subcat = Cell(categoryCell.row - 1, "C")
    Else

        complCount = complCount + 0
        subcat = Cell(categoryCell.row - 1, "C")
    End If

Loop
Complt = complCount / numberofsubs
End Function
```

Comment: FWIW, if you want a piece of code that *returns a value*, what you want is a `Function`, not a `Sub`. If that piece of code has side-effects on application/worksheet state, you probably want that to be a `Sub`.

Comment: That is what I was heading for but I was unsure if i needed to call a sub from the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with a worksheet formula when adding a helper column.

In the help column check if the completion date is before or on the due date:

`=IF(H7<=G7,1,0)` For example in K7

Then put this formula in J6 to check for the following ten rows if they contain Yieldsub, and if they are delivered on time.

`=SumIf(R[1]K[-8]:R[10]K[-8],RK[-8]&"sub",R[1]K[1]:R[10]K[1])`

Comment: This list stacks on top of its self, wouldn't this cause error if there are two "Yield" items  on top of each other?

Comment: @ThomasBreakell What do you mean with "stacks on top of its self"?

Comment: When you "Add Item" copys the template and pastes it at the last row. Also the number of subs is variable to each item. So as a default it creates 3, but the items could have anywhere from 0 to 10+.

Comment: Well you can simply replace 10 with a larger number to accomodate your needs. As the formula uses RK style references it doesn't really matter where you paste it as it uses relative ranges compared to the cell the formula is in.